# gpus parameter in multi-gpu-model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, multi-gpu

I use keras(v2.2.4) with tensorflow(v1.12.0) as backend(Python 3.6.7). I want to implement a multi-gpu model use `multi-gpu-model` in `keras.utils`.

There are 10 gpus in the ubuntu machine and `0,1,2,9` is what I can use. So I wrote `multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=[0, 1, 2, 9])`, but it threw the error:

```
ValueError: To call `multi_gpu_model` with `gpus=[0, 1, 
2, 9]`, we expect the following devices to be available: 
['/cpu:0', '/gpu:0', '/gpu:1', '/gpu:2', '/gpu:9']. However 
this machine only has: ['/cpu:0', '/xla_gpu:0', '/xla_cpu:0', 
'/gpu:0', '/gpu:1', '/gpu:2', '/gpu:3']. Try reducing `gpus`.
```

The machine names are not consistent with those in tensorflow. When I changed the code to `multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=[0, 1, 2, 3])`, it used all my machines(as the figure shows). I am very confused. How can I implement the multi-gpu-model using `0,1,2,9` gpus?

[image]

Comment: Would the code work if `gpus=[0, 1, 2]`? I am asking this because I guess `/gpu:9` is not returned by `_get_available_devices()`, aka, not available. See [source code here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/multi_gpu_utils.py).

Comment: @Richard_wth yes, `gpus=[0, 1, 2, 3]`worked, so `gpus=[0,1,2]` will work,too. The question is why keras implement a different way of using gpus with tensorflow when using tensorflow as backend?  And I donot see a way to use `[0, 1, 2, 9]` gpus assigned to me.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was meant to ask if GPU 4-9 have indeed been identified by TF. If `gpus=[0, 1, 2]`, would the code uses all memory of `/gpu:3`? Would the code work if `gpus=something larger than 3`? You may also simply try code like `with tf.device('/gpu:9'): a = b*c` to see if it gives errors.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion,too. I changed to `0,1,2` but forgot to run `nvidia-smi`, I found the speed is lower than `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1,2,9"`, so I used gpus in this way now.